# SQLite3 in Adobe Plugin extensions

Tags: adobe, adobe-illustrator

I have developed a plugin for Adobe Illustrator and I am trying to use `sqlite3` or `better-sqlite3` node packages instead of mySQL. But I am getting following errors on Mac and Windows.

**Windows** (using `sqlite3`)

> Uncaught Error: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.

[image: Windows error image when using sqlite3]

**Mac** (using `better-sqlite3`)

> Uncaught Error: dlopen(...): no suitable image found.
>   Did find: [...] code signature in (...) not valid for use in process using Library Validation: mapped file has no cdhash, completely unsigned? Code has to be at least ad-hoc signed.

[image: Mac error image when using better-sqlite3]

Is it possible to use `sqlite3` or `better-sqlite3` in Adobe plugins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome here,

This is not possible because Sqlite3 and all its wrapper uses Node C++ Addon and not js package. C++ addons are not supported by CEP as per the official word.

Link for the reference

https://github.com/Adobe-CEP/CEP-Resources/issues/70